# How to refer to Sub Elements of a vector within a For loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, automation, element

I'm trying to change the data for stock search with Yahoo finance. I'm trying to automate a web browser to give the Yahoo URL for each stock. I want to use ISIN codes with Yahoo Finance.

I'm using a simple 1 row excel sheet (csv file) with stock names on them in a column like:

```
   A          B         C
1 Apple
2 Google
3 Facebook
4 Amazon
5 Tesla
```

I have copied the url for the website.
I want the copied url in each element of the vector.

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
dev.off()

library(KeyboardSimulator)
Target_Names <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=F)
for (i in 1:nrow(Target_Names)){
  Name=as.character(Target_Names[i,1])
#Name= "Apple"
#Name="Facebook"
#Name="Google"

mouse.get_cursor()

mouse.move(904, 130, duration = 2, step_ratio = 0.01)
mouse.click(button = "left", hold = F)
writeClipboard(Name)
keybd.press('Ctrl', hold = T)
keybd.press('v')
keybd.release('ctrl')
Sys.sleep(2)
mouse.move(1195,  125, duration = 2, step_ratio = 0.01)
mouse.click(button = "left", hold = F)
Sys.sleep(5)
mouse.move(850, 60, duration = 2, step_ratio = 0.01)
mouse.click(button = "left", hold = F)
Sys.sleep(2)
keybd.press('Ctrl', hold = T)
keybd.press('a')
keybd.release('ctrl')
Sys.sleep(2)
keybd.press('Ctrl', hold = T)
keybd.press('c')
keybd.release('ctrl')
Sys.sleep(2)

copdat[] <- read.delim("clipboard")
}
```

The only problem is the last line. I put in

```
copdat[i]
copdat[,i]
copdat[1,i]
```

but it all failed.

If I use the code.

```
copdat[1]
copdat[2]
```

it works, but I want it for each element of the for Loop.

I don't really understand vectors or Sub elements and how to get them. If you could explain that too it would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does "it all failed" mean? Did you get an error of some sort? Are you initializing the vector before the loop? Something like `copdat <- character(nrow(Target_Names))`? Or are you intending to create a data.frame? Do you actually have more than one column that needs to be read by `read.delim`? or are you just reading a single character vector?

Comment: `[` is an extraction function. When you enter `copdat[1]` you are asking R to extract the first element of an object (or assign a value to it) that your code has not yet created. You will get an error message. As pointed out in the previous comment, this object needs to exist first. You can do that 'on the fly' by entering `copdat <- 1` or assigning a vector to the name.
`read.delim` returns a data frame from a file. Do you know anything about the data in this file?

Comment: I show the CSV file in the first line of code as it would be seen in excel. The first iteration  would search the term "Apple", second "Google", third "Facebook" etc. All I want is how to make the first element of the vector copdat equal the copied url for the search term "Apple", the second element of of copdat equal the copied url for the search term  "Google". All I want is a one column vector. I can create a database later by looking at creating a data frame examples on stackoverflow or YouTube. I want a very basic 1 column vector for me to learn and for others to see too in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay, after a few hours of searching on StackOverflow, I found a solution that works for me. I'll find how to merge vectors later.

This is to show anyone that wants to automate work. Anyone who wants to have a column of search results, put them in the first column of an excel sheet, and save it as a .CSV file.

internet automation and web scaping with search results and then get the corresponding values that they want, instead of doing it over and over again.

```
# Clear screen RStudio
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
dev.off()

#Library for keyboard and mouse automation
library(KeyboardSimulator)

#Choose Excel CSV file with first Column data
Target_Names <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=F)

#define Vectors before for Loop so as to not override them
copdat<- vector()
copdat1 <- vector()

#'copying' for Loop ----
for (i in 1:nrow(Target_Names)){
  Name=as.character(Target_Names[i,1])

# Get co-ordinates of mouse on screen by running this code depending where your mouse is
mouse.get_cursor()

#Clicking on screen, surfing web etc to get data to copy ----
mouse.move(725, 122, duration = 2, step_ratio = 0.01)
mouse.click(button = "left", hold = F)
writeClipboard(Name)
keybd.press('Ctrl', hold = T)
keybd.press('v')
keybd.release('ctrl')
Sys.sleep(2)
mouse.move(959, 121, duration = 2, step_ratio = 0.01)
mouse.click(button = "left", hold = F)
Sys.sleep(5)
mouse.move(712,  58, duration = 2, step_ratio = 0.01)
mouse.click(button = "left", hold = F)
Sys.sleep(2)
keybd.press('Ctrl', hold = T)
keybd.press('a')
keybd.release('ctrl')
Sys.sleep(2)

# the part of copying data
keybd.press('Ctrl', hold = T)
keybd.press('c')
keybd.release('ctrl')
Sys.sleep(2)

#Copying data to vectors described above and storing them
copdat1 <- read.delim("clipboard")
copdat<-append(copdat,copdat1)
}

#After 'copying' for loop ----

#Merge Vectors to create Data Frames etc.
```